# Why does a Norm Form have rational coefficients?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, diophantine-equations, normed-spaces, diophantine-approximation

[From Wolfgang Schmidt's "Diophantine Approximation and Diophantine Equations"]

"Let $K$ be a number field with $[K:\mathbb{Q}] = d$ and $L(X)$ be a linear form, say $L(X) = L(x_1,\dots,x_n) = \alpha_1x_1 +\dots+\alpha_nx_n$ with $\alpha_j \in K$. Suppose that $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$. Then $n\le d$ and $L$ will not vanish on $\mathbb{Q}^n \backslash 0$. As usual, denote the embeddings of $K$ into $\mathbb{C}$ by $\alpha \to \alpha^{(i)}, (i=1,\dots,d)$ and write $L^{(i)}(X) = \alpha_1^{(i)}x_1+\dots+\alpha_n^{(i)}x_n$. We write

$$N(L(X)) = \prod_{i=1}^d L^{(i)}(X).$$

A *norm form* is any form $F$ of the type $F(X) = cN(L(X))$ for some $L$ as above and $c \in Q^{*}$. For a norm form $F$, we have $F(X) \in \mathbb{Q}[X]$."

**Question:**

Why do we have $F(X) \in \mathbb{Q}[X]$?

For fixed $j$, I can see that $\prod_{i=1}^{d}\alpha_j^{(i)} \in \mathbb{Q}$. But what happens when we have coefficients in $F(X)$ of the form $\alpha_{j_1}^{(1)}\alpha_{j_2}^{(2)}\dots\alpha_{j_d}^{(d)}$ where some of the $j_k$'s are different?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you done Galois Theory?

Comment: Hi Gerry, yes, but perhaps I'm missing something straightforward. Could you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The coefficients in the norm form are invariant under the action of the Galois group, so they are in the ground field.

Comment: Thanks Gerry. Perhaps I'm missing some short-cuts, but I don't think it is that trivial to see that the coefficients in the Norm Form are invariant under the action of the Galois group, especially when d is a large number (but n is not). I have worked out some simple cases and observed the patterns. In the general case, I think we need to use in some way the fact that the degree of each $\alpha_j$ divides d.

Comment: If $\sigma$ takes $\alpha_i^{(j)}$ to $\alpha_i^{(k)}$ for all $i$, then it takes $L^{(j)}(X)$ to $L^{(k)}(X)$, so it just permutes the terms in the product that defines $N(L(X))$.

Comment: Ah I see, finally. Thanks for your elaboration. I should have focused on the effects of the Galois group on the $L^{(i)}(X)$'s, and not the individual $\alpha_j$'s. Thanks again for your help.